# RAD 7.5 Out of memory exceptions

Tags: websphere, rad

I am working in RAD 7.5, Using WAS 7.0 Server. When I tried to start the server facing, I get `Out of Memory exception`. Detail error message is pasted below:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at java.lang.String.toCharArray(String.java:1101 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to increase the available memory to your Java VM. You can do this by a switch to the interpreter.